# ListView ReorderMode XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, drag-and-drop, windows-phone-8.1

I'm stuck in a problem about WP8.1:

I have a ListView with ReorderMode = "Enabled"; so it is draggable and the user can reorder the list by dragging.

The problem is that when a listview is inside the ReorderMode state, its items become smaller, ther opacity diminishes, and the items are **constantly moving around!!** I'm looking for a way to avoid these secondary effects of the ReorderMode.

Everything would be much easier if the properties CanDragItems, CanReorder and AllowDrop worked in WP8.1, but it seems that they do not...

Does Anyone have any idea about how to prevent this behaviour from happening?

```
                    <ListView x:Name="SitesListContainer"
                            DataContext="{Binding RouteResultsVM.SelectedRoute.PlacesNotCurrentPosition, Mode=TwoWay}"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                            HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                            Background="{x:Null}"
                            SelectionChanged="SitesListContainer_SelectionChanged" 
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this but try to get the default listview datetemplate and remove `<ReorderThemeTransition />` that might work. here is the link [ListView Default style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj709922.aspx)

Comment: Does anyone have an idea?